# How to add multiple OR coming from a list of String in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a list of values (String) and I have to fetch values from database if a criteria matches the first value of the list OR the second value OR the third value and so on...

P.S.: In my class, I have this String variable named property which must be matched with those values contained in the list.

Comment: Use [`Predicate.in`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/Expression.html#in-java.util.Collection-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the simplest way I know is:

```
SimpleExpression restrictionsList[] = new SimpleExpression[list.size()];
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    restrictionsList[i] = Restrictions.eq("property", list.get(i));
criteria.add(Restrictions.or(restrictionsList));
```

Comment: Thanks, dude. I'll test it and I'll send you a feedback here.

Comment: I adapted to the code I have here and it worked perfectly. Thanks, again.